# Use relation via pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Real to use relation from pivot table model?
have Table:

products

| id | slug |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1-product |

store

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | product |

product_store

| id | product_id | store_id | code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1-product | 1 | 123456 |
| 2 | 1-product | 2 | 123456 |

product_store_price

| id | product_store_id | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 |

Model Product have

```
public  function stores()
    {
    return $this->
belongsToMany(
'App\Models\Store',
'product_store_links',
'product_id',
'store_id'
)->withPivot('code','id');
    }
```

Model ProductStore

```
    public function prices()
    {
        return $this->
        hasMany('App\Models\ProductStorePrice','product_store_link_id','id');
    }
```

can I use something like this?

```
$product= Product::find(1)->stores[0]->pivot->prices;
```

Comment: what is your problem? did you try your code?

Comment: why is the price in a seperate table, is it not a 1 to 1 relation with product_store table ?

Comment: @N69S I use product_store_price as price history table

Comment: @GiacomoM yeah I tried receive null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a one to many relationship between `product_store` table and `product_store_price` table. And `product_store` table is an intermediate table between `products` and `stores` table.

In many to many relationship between `products` and `stores` table, `product_store` table is just an intermediate table which is sometimes omitted and access their additional fields via pivot. But in this case you will need a model for `product_store` since it will also have a relationship with `product_store_price` table.

To create a model for pivot table in Laravel, you have to extend the model with `Pivot`. Then you can have a one to many relationship with `ProductStorePrice` model.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class ProductStore extends Pivot
{
    public function prices()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductStorePrice::class);
    }
}
```

And to access `product_store` rows from either `product` or `store`, you will need a one to many relationship.

```
// Product model, Store model

public function productStores()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ProductStore::class);
}
```

Then you can access them through

```
$productStores = $product->productStores; // from product
$productStores = $store->productStores; // from store

foreach($productStores as $productStore) {
    $productStore->prices;
}
```

Comment: also can i ask, i use all tables name ending with ```s``` like ```product_stores```, rules of laravel, but now I have an issue that laravel  automatically don't add ```s``` to queue  for ProductStore Model 
```Table 'test.product_store' doesn't  exist```
before models created via ```php artisan make:model ProductStore --migration```

Comment: @Hik200 for pivot table, Laravel rule is just a singular product_store